# Understanding a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I've been seeing queries like the one below more commonly now than ever. What I'm lost at is 'p.title', the 'as' clause, and 'FROM Posts p'. Anybody care to explain these parts to me or refer me to resources as I have no clue what to search for in Google?

```
SELECT p.title, SUBSTR(p.post,1,300) as post 
FROM Posts p 
WHERE p.title LIKE '%{$q}%' 
  OR p.post LIKE '%{$q}%'");
```

Comment: Somebody needs to read through the MySQL manual. Search for "aliases".

Comment: And I don't see the relevance to PHP.

Comment: `substr(p.post,1,300)` is probably the snippet, I'm not ok with this since the *post* field can contain html elements and splitting into it can lead to wrong rendering in the document. (e.g. '<p>hello</')
it's not the topic..but take it in consideration @MichaelGrigsby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"p.title" is connected to "from Posts p". "p" is an alias. In the "from" segment, if you add such alias, you can refer everywhere in the query to columns of this table by using the alias prefix. That's useful for joins in particular, when you join on the same tables more than once or have columns with the same name in different tables.

the "as" is just about display. It will display the title specified after instead of the original column title in the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.title, SUBSTR(p.post,1,300) AS post 
FROM Posts p 
WHERE p.title LIKE '%{$q}%' OR p.post LIKE '%{$q}%'"
```

As shown in the 2nd line, the "p" is an alias for the 'Posts'-Table. The AS-clause names the column in the result (in this case "post");

Answer (score 1):

p in your query is called Referal / Alias to the table. very comman in practice and useful when working with multiple tables having same field names.

more details are on

http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p8.php

Answer (score 0):

it is alias of that table ..when I write query like select * from Post P means i have to write p. before each and every column of that table in particular that query... it is not that much confusing...

Answer (score 0):

`FROM Posts p` - here, p is an alias of the table `Posts`. This means that in the rest of the query, you can use p instead of the table name Posts.
Also you can also use `FROM Posts as p` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The dotted notation is in the format of `table.column`. The `as` keyword indicates an alias, you can select `column1` as `column456`. `FROM Posts p` will let you use `p` as shorthand notation in the query when referring to the `Posts` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "AS" to make an alias (column name) which you can later retrieve in php `$result['post']`. The same goes for "Posts p" it is shorthand for "Posts as p" which in return lets you use `p` as the table name in the rest of the query

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the query seems to implement a very simple search engine.  `SUBSTR(p.post,1,300)` will return the first 200 characters of the post text.  As the resultset would then have a column in it called `SUBSTR(p.post,1,300)` the additional AS clause will rename this column to `post`.

LIKE is a string matching function built into MySQL that lets you do simple pattern matching on strings.  % is a wildcard matching any sequence of characters.  $q is probably a placeholder that gets replaced with the string that will actually be searched for when the query is run for real.

Answer (score 0):

`FROM Posts p` is short for `FROM Posts AS p`, which creates an *alias* for the table name in the query. It means you can write a slightly shorter query.

The author then backtracks slightly by writing out `p.title` for some reason, which here is equivalent to `title` (or `Posts.title` if he hadn't created the alias).